# mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied when using password in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

There are multiple threads to this problem, however, they don't conform to my, because the problems the other users have, are getting fixed with solutions that don't work for me.

I want to do a mysqldump of a remote database, which works without problems, when I do it like this

`mysqldump -u {username} -p -h {ip} {dbname} > backup.sql`

I get a password prompt, type it in, and get the backup created. However, when I want to do this without the password prompt, I added my login data to the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` which is the only `my.cnf` file I have.

My `[mysqldump]` section looks like this

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
user={username}
password={password}
```

But here I'm getting the error

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user '{username}'@'{ip}' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

How can I make it work without password prompt?

Maybe it's important to say, that I'm writing the info about `[myqsldump]` on my local `my.cnf` and not the remote `my.cnf`, since I'm trying to dump a remote database

Answer (score 0):

Try storing password in `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable instead.

Or use `--login-path=somepath` and [.mylogin.cnf with mysql_config_editor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a solution. More like an alternative way, but there must be a way, how I can achieve it through the my.cnf

Comment: Added `.mylogin.cnf` option